# How to see what current prompt definition

Tags: zsh, prompt

I'm moving from bash to zsh and getting stuck on the prompt. My Manjaro defines it one way, Ubuntu another.

So I like, e.g. the prompt called "clint". But it's not exactly what I want. I can find more or less adequate resources that help me define my own prompt, but I don't know how this particular one is composed.

Where can I find its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` stores its prompt setups and defintions in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/`.

So if you want to take a look what `prompt clint` does behind the curtains, first find the right file:

```
$ ls /usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/*clint*
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/prompt_clint_setup
```

And open it in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $PS1
```

And to find where it is defined, try the commmand below:

```
grep 'PS1' $HOME/.bash{rc,_profile}
```

Comment: huh, PS1 seems to work. As for the rest of your answer, this is zsh, not bash. the "built-in" prompt is definitely not defined anywhere in my home.